# Importing Variable that's not initially set

Tags: python, string, import, pygame

I'm trying to take a variable containing a name and display it on a certificate but the variable isn't actually set until the user hits return as shown below, self.value is set by a user's input.

```
#File 1 Containing Varible
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == K_BACKSPACE: self.value = self.value[:-1]
    elif event.key == K_LSHIFT or event.key == K_RSHIFT: self.shifted = True
    elif event.key == K_SPACE: self.value += ' '
    elif event.key == K_RETURN:
        Name = self.value
        execfile('Certificate.py')
```

I import the file the variable is stored in and try to print the variable just to test by it says:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Name'
```

Why is this happening?

```
#File2 where i'm trying to input the variable to.  
import pygame, sys, eztext
from pygame.locals import *
print eztext.Name
```

EDIT: Thank you to those who have answered so far but I don't think i've explained the problem properly, the eztext file is a module that allows for the user to type their name on the screen which is then stored in self.value and then the variable "Name" I need the variable "Name" with the contents of what the person has typed to be imported into the second file.

Comment: So what should happen if file2 is executed before the user has entered their name? (because it looks to me like file2's `print` statement is reached first)

Comment: It shouldn't be, it's the very last thing to be executed as a sort a certificate with the users name and score (Haven't added score yet) If you mean that if the user just presses enter without typing i'll put in something to stop that later on

Comment: is file2 `Certificate.py`?

Comment: It looks like your file 1 snippet is part of a class. If you're declaring `Name` within a method of that class, `Name` only exists within that method. That's probably why `print eztext.Name` from file2 fails. Instead of using `Name`, can't you just access the class's `self.value` attribute directly?

Comment: After a while of tinkering around blindly.. i've figured it out, thank you so much for you help, i'd upvote but I don't have the rep yet

Comment: You should post your solution then, in case other people end up here with the same problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Name` variable doesn't exist by the time you call `print eztext.Name`.

Try setting it to `None` or something at the beginning.

```
Name = None

#File 1 Containing Varible
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == K_BACKSPACE: self.value = self.value[:-1]
    elif event.key == K_LSHIFT or event.key == K_RSHIFT: self.shifted = True
    elif event.key == K_SPACE: self.value += ' '
    elif event.key == K_RETURN:
        Name = self.value
        execfile('Certificate.py')
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I want it to grab the variable after the user has input their name, doing what you've said simply gives me the output of "None"

Comment: @user3415453, do you mean you don't want to run file2 until after the user has entered their name?

Comment: No i'm running it immediately after but now all i'm getting is "None"

Comment: Yeah because `Name = self.value` never gets hit.

Answer (score 0):

Because Python doesn't require declarations, eztext.Name doesn't exist until it's set. The best way to handle this is to explicitly define `Name = None` at the beginning of the eztext file.

However, if you can't modify eztext for some reason, you can also do something like this:

```
#File2 where i'm trying to input the variable to.  
import pygame, sys, eztext
from pygame.locals import *

try:
    print eztext.Name
except AttributeError:
    print "eztext has no name."
```